# Gitlab container registry behind reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, gitlab, container-registry

I found a lot of questions on StackOverflow with the same title as this question.

But none of the questions or answers could help me to solve my problem

*(I use `example.com` instead of my own domain).*

when I try to login to my registry like this:

```
docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
```

I get this error:

```sh
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.example.com/v2/: denied: access forbidden
```

and if I curl the url:

```
curl https://registry.example.com/v2/
```

I get this json as a response.

```json
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

I have setup Gitlab with a docker-compose file:

```yaml
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com'
      nginx['listen_port'] = 8081
      nginx['listen_https'] = false
      registry_external_url 'https://registry.example.com'
      registry['registry_http_addr'] = "gitlab.example.com:5050"
      registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5005
      registry_nginx['listen_https'] = false
  ports:
    - '8081:8081'
    - '5050:5005'
    - '22:22'
  volumes:
    - '/home/user/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/home/user/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/home/user/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

I have setup my NGINX like this with (certbot/LetsEncrypt):

```
server {
    server_name registry.example.com www.registry.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.30:5050;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.registry.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = registry.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name registry.example.com www.registry.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```